# Is XNA still used for Windows game development?

Tags: xna

Last time I looked at XNA it was at version 4 and you could use it to develop C# games that ran on Windows, or Windows Phone, or Xbox 360.

Just been poking around again and I can't get any sense out of what the current state of play is.

The emphasis is very very much on Windows phone 7.5, then to a lesser extent 360, and for Windows you just get pointed at the DirectX SDK.

Has it been re-envisioned again? At some point I remember the C# version disappeared and you only had the C++ version, I sort of lost interest then.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question, exactly?  Microsoft is always re-envisioning things.  Is your question, "Is there one ring to rule them all?"

Comment: No Rob, is XNA still used for Windows app development.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22292

Comment: Interesting. I seem to remember it was only recently that Microsoft backed down on making Visual Studio Express on Windows 8 only do Metro apps. I've actually just downloaded it. I'm running on Windows 8 and there are a few issues with the install, so we'll see if I get around that. Seems like you need latest GFW among other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still used for windows 7 development. And runs fine. I use it all the time.

The future of it for windows 8 is unclear. All the topic on different sites are just ideas, and nobody "really" seems to know. Its just rumors really. So we will just have to see.

Apparently Windows 8 can run it in desktop mode, But not metro. As it seems Microsoft just loves HTML 5 and JS now.

I wouldnt say its focused on XBOX and Wp7 completely, alot of those games dont seem to be very good, and it dosent seem to have attracted big AAA titles to those platforms, But I have seen many nice games with XNA for windows (Terraria, Magicka)

Comment: I'm running Windows 8 here, and generally it feels like Windows 7 with a different start menu. Ok, that's a gross over simplification, but it's ok. The OS won't be an issue, just the tools possibly